# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException - syntax error in sql

Tags: c#, sql, syntax-error

I have a syntax error in this SQL:

```
string sSql = $"SELECT OxygenTankInDetailTBL.HBedNameID, 
                       OxygenTankInDetailTBL.LocationHB 
                FROM OxygenTankInDetailTBL 
                INNER JOIN SectionsNameTBL ON (SectionsNameTBL.SectionID = OxygenTankInDetailTBL.LocationHB 
                                           AND SectionsNameTBL.LocationG = '{locationG}') 
                INNER JOIN OxygenTankTBL ON (OxygenTankTBL.HBedID = OxygenTankInDetailTBL.HBedNameID 
                                         AND OxygenTankTBL.IsActive= {true});";
```

The error is:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(SectionsNameTBL.SectionID = OxygenTankInDetailTBL.LocationHB AND SectionsNameTBL.LocationG = 'agaf1') INNER JOIN OxygenTankTBL ON(OxygenTankTBL.HBedID = OxygenTankInDetailTBL.HBedNameID AND OxygenTankTBL.IsActive= True'.'

Thanks

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Please don't use string concatenation for sql commands, use real parameters (look up "sql injection")

Comment: Are you sure `OxygenTankTBL.IsActive= True` is valid for your DBMS?

Comment: Why are you using oledb instead of SQLClient library?  The query statement may be different with the two libraries.  Try changing the connection string to the SQLClient library.

Comment: Are you, perhaps missing single quotes around LocationHB and/or HBedNameID?

Comment: tnk for trying to help! , it is vaild for my DBMs and all the names of the tables and columns are correct

Comment: What *is* your DBMS? Just to check, try `OxygenTankTBL.IsActive=1` (instead of =True). What is the datatype of OxygenTankTBL.IsActive?

Comment: the type is bool , and unfortunately it still doesnt work with 1

Comment: : 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''.' - on which query does he talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If yor DBMS is MS Access, see this example.
I guess, you can JOIN 1 table or subQuery in JOIN operation. Wrap additional joins in a subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM SectionsNameTBL 
RIGHT JOIN (
       OxygenTankTBL RIGHT JOIN OxygenTankInDetailTBL 
        ON OxygenTankTBL.HBedID = OxygenTankInDetailTBL.HBedNameID
   ) 
  ON SectionsNameTBL.SectionID = OxygenTankInDetailTBL.LocationHB
WHERE SectionsNameTBL.LocationG = 'agaf1'
  AND OxygenTankTBL.IsActive= true
;
```